# Curves on an irreducible algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is it true that any two points of an irreducible algebraic variety lie on some irreducible curve? My thought was to prove this for quasiprojective varieties by taking hyperplane sections repeatedly, but this sometimes gives reducible curves.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62843/path-connectedness-of-varieties

Comment: Thanks! Should have checked.

Comment: Actually this question is hard to search for, I just happened to remember that someone had titled the question "path connectedness of varieties."